# Using with (nolock) hint in queries or adoconnection with lower isolationlevel

Tags: delphi, transactions, adoconnection

I have been working on a huge enterprise application with very fast data entry (200 client and 80~120 records per second).

We only have one tadoconnection for the whole application, with read commit isolation level. Many of my forms are using tadodataset for viewing data.

We don't need to be exact, but every time the forms loads slowly. This is due to locking mechanism, in other words uncommitted records not very important and fast loading is.

We have 2 choices:

- use `with (nolock)` in all queries
- add another connection with read uncommitted isolation level

I personally prefer `with (nolock)` because managing multiple connections is not simple, but I want to know what is benefits of either method.

Comment: Check out [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to be used everywhere - quite the contrary! Read this counterpoint opinion and see how that affects you

Comment: What do you mean by "ADO.NET" in the context of a Delphi application?

Comment: what TADOQuery.LockType you are using?

Comment: i never changed it it should be default